# Attempted import error: 'CardAction' is not exported from '@material-ui/core'

Tags: javascript, debugging, material-ui, updates

I'm working on a react app and I'm trying to import CardAction from @material-ui but then:

```
Attempted import error: 'CardAction' is not exported from '@material-ui/core'.
```

So obviously I went to Stackoverflow and I have a question:

Is CardAction only available in material-ui v5 and if so how do I install it?

Thank you!

Comment: It's `CardActions` not `CardAction`

Comment: 2 out of 3 of your questions are typo related...